# How can I reference values dynamically from 3 columns in another sheet based on a value in cell?

Tags: excel, list

I have a dropdown list of 104 values in column F. I want if any of the values is selected from that list cloumn, a corresponding value should be referenced from sheet and be inserted the cell in Column i .

If a  value is selected in sheet 1 column F then it should match it with a similar value in sheet 2 columnA and also select the value corresponding value in Sheet 2 column B and go back and insert it in sheet 1 Column i.

Please note that each of the 104 values in column F has its corresponding value from a cell address of another worksheet

worksheet with dropdown list column F and inserted value column I
[image: worksheet with referenced value]

worksheet with referenced value
[image: worksheet with dropdown list]

Answer (score 0):

That calls the use of two possible functions:
The first is VLOOKUP, which you can find about in here:
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

(**please note the 4th parameter!!!!**)

The second combination is index/match, which I think is more appropriate for your situation:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/

Or here:
https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Less theoretical but with the best explanation:

http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

more complicated but fits your purpose better

Index/match with more than one column to match against:
https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I have used Vlookup function for days now but can't still get it right. I was also trying using IF function but I have to use 104 IF statements which has a limit of 64 nested levels and I don't have office 365 to use IFS

Comment: @Edwinfad; could you please post the code for the vlookup? Are you sure you set the range right (since it's not for the entire column?) please note that you have many hidden columns, that's why I thought Index/Match is a better option. If you have 6 columns hidden you need to add them to the calculation of the column number from which you need to grab the value from

Comment: I don't have VLOOKUP code anymore because I have tried a lot of things but didn't still get it right. I will appreciate a clearer example. If the a value is selected in sheet 1 column F then it should match it with a similar value in sheet 2 column A and also select the value corresponding value in Sheet 2 column B and go back and insert it in sheet 1 Column i.

Comment: @Edwinfad; use index/match since there you can use more than one column, I've edited my answer

Comment: I have gone through them but still a bit confusing.

Comment: I have gone through them but still seems not appropriate for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

use Index/Match

=Index("select the data that you want displayed",match("common data", "common data",0))

I use this a ton when pulling data from multiple tabs. 
=index(List of Customers,match(tab1_CustomerID, tab2_CustomerID,0))

hope this helps!

Comment: I will appreciate a clearer example. If the a value is selected in sheet 1 column F then it should match it with a similar value in sheet 2 columnA and also select the value corresponding value in Sheet 2 column B and go back and insert it in sheet 1 Column i.

Comment: ok. say that you have on sheet 1 is the sales data with accounts, account ID's, territory ID and sales performance and then lets say sheet 2 has a sales associates name, assigned territories. Lets say your goal is to insert a column on sheet 1 so you can identify the sale associate to their sales data. The formula would look like this: =index(sheet2[Sales Associate],match(sheet1[TerritoryID],sheet2[territoryID],0))